# How to test the sum of 2 elements in a list for each pair of elements

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am trying to analyse if a pair of elements in a list equal to a certain number n. Let's say I have n=5 and my list is ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6']. Here, we can see that 4+1=5 and 3+2=5. I want to display ONLY this : Elements 4 and 1 =5

How do I make a loop that tests all pairs of number (so a group of 2 numbers) ? I want the output to be the first valid pair. So, how do I make a loop that do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this you asking?

```
input=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5','6']
n=5
for i in input:
    for j in input:
        if int(i)+int(j)==n:
            print(i,"+",j,"=",n)
```

output

```
1 + 4 = 5
2 + 3 = 5
3 + 2 = 5
4 + 1 = 5
```